# how to split lines into an from txt file into a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, split

I have a text file of client data that looks like this

```
    :client objects (
    : (ThomasSmith
                :AdminInfo (
                    :client_uid ("{C6DD9C9C-964A-4BE5-30F1-3D64A87F73A6}")
                    :nickName (Tom)
                    )

                :addr ("1234 Pear Street")
                :city (Charlotte)
                :state (NC)
                :zip (12345)
                :phone ("555-555-5555")
                :email ("tom@someemailaddress.com")
                :gender (male)

            )       

    : (Jonathan Thomson
                :AdminInfo (
                    :client_uid ("{C6DD9C9C-964A-4BE5-30F1-3D64A87F73A7}")
                    :nickName (John)
                    )

                :addr ("5678 Apple Street")
                :city ("New York")
                :state (
                    :AdminInfo (
                    :chkpf_uid(:""{ B056A094-3164-42C9-888F-11071C1FCD9B}"")
                    :global_level(1)
                )
)
                :zip (56789)
                :phone ("555-444-6666")
                :email ("John@someemailaddress.com")
            )
    )
```

I need to be able to parse parts of each client into a list or datatable. What I'm stuck with is starting reading the file at nameofclient, and stopping my read at the end of that client and not picking up data from nameofclient2. is there a way to stop reading my file when a specific word or pattern shows up?
One of the problems I don't know how to solve is that each client could have a different number of attributes, so I cannot hard code a number of lines I will have to regex for a pattern of ":([a-z]" or something like that. Ideally i want this in a datatable formatted similar to this:

```
    Name of customer | Attribute    
    ------------------------------
    Customer1        | Address(XXXXXX)
    Customer1        | ZipCode(XXXXXX)
    Customer1        | Etc...
    Customer2        | .....
    Customer2        | .....
```

Anyway, I am brand new to coding and I don't have enough experience yet to get this to work. Here is what I have Tried:

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        ruleset rs = new ruleset();
        System.IO.StreamReader br = new System.IO.StreamReader("f");

        string line = string.Empty;         
        bool GroupTrue = false;
        int numObjects1 = 0;          
        string cGroupName = "";

        while ((line = br.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(":(client_objects"))
            {
                GroupTrue = true;

                string[] tempArray = line.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                cGroupName = tempArray[tempArray.Length - 1];
            }
            else if (GroupTrue && !Regex.IsMatch(line, "") && (numObjects1 < 50))
            {
                numObjects1 = numObjects1 + 1;

                cGroup cGroup = new cGroup(cGroupName, line);


                rs.addGroups(cGroup);
            }
            else if (GroupTrue && Regex.IsMatch(line, ".*\\b.*"))
            {
                GroupTrue = false;
            }
        }
    }

}

public class cGroup
{
    public string attribute;
    public string groups;

    public cGroup(String cGroupName, String line)
    {
        this.groups = cGroupName;
        this.attribute = line;
    }

}
public class ruleset
{
    //cGroup cResult = new cGroup();
    public List<cGroup> cGroups = new List<cGroup>();
    public void addGroups(cGroup cGroups)
    {
        this.cGroups.Add(cGroups);
    }
}
```

Comment: What format is that?  Perhaps there is a library that already works with that particular format.

Comment: It looks like a lisp plist...

Comment: How about an actual data run (at least show the uniqueness of customer vs customer)? Do addresses span multiple lines or is the whole address on one line?

Comment: @OmegaMan, the only unique values  would be the name of client and the client_uid. I have never seen an attribute span multiple lines.

Comment: I will attempt a reply, but I will work off of a guess as what the data `XXXXXX` looks like. If I provide a regex for that and the reply is, "Oh the data doesn't look like that, you missed YYYY". That is my concern in answering this...so if can you fill in the XXXX with actual (fake) data which mimics what is shown, that will help with a better more concise answer.

Comment: Why is there `: ` in front of name of client 2 and and not in front of nameofclient1? Is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks @OmegaMan!, I have updated the question with realistic data. there should have been a : in front of client 1. I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the bias against regex because people are not willing to learn the basics. By using these basic principles (and avoiding the use of the `.*` in regex to consume all) of

- Use `+` one or more verses `*` zero or more (only use `*` sparingly).
- `( )` Basic match capture, we are interested in what is in the parenthesis
- `(?<{Name is here}> )` Named match capture for easier extraction of match data.
- `[^ ]+` The *not* set, consume until you hit the character(s) after the `^`.

So with those rules we build upon each one and find what I call *anchors* in the data. That is where we can guide the regex parser to and the use the named match captures to *consume* the data.

### Pattern

Here is the pattern in a C# variable.

```
string pattern = @"
:\s+\(                 # Anchor text of Operation Start
(?<Name>[^\r\n]+)  # Named capture into `Name` match capture.
[^:]+:AdminInfo[^:]+   # More whitespace to admin and into first admin node.
    (                    # 1 to many admin nodes start.
      :                  # Anchor for admin node
      (?<ADKey>[^\s]+)       # Node key name into `ADKey` match capture
        \s+\(\x22?            # Anchor of `(` and possible quote (\x22) Start
       (?<ADValue>[^\x22\)]+) # Value of admin node
      \x22?\)\s+              # Anchor optional quote and `)` End
     )+                  # 1 to many admin nodes end
 \)                    # Close of Admin Info
 (                   # 1 to many nodes start.
    [^:]+:           # Consume whitespace and `:` anchor
    (?<Key>[^\s]+)      # Node name into match capture group `Key`
        \s+\(\x22?       # Anchor of `(` and possible quote (\x22) start
    (?<Value>[^\x22\)]+) # Value of admin node
      \x22?\)\s+         # Anchor End
  )+            # 1 to many nodes end
\s*\)           # Close of whole operation END";
```

Note the named match captures of `Name`, `ADKey`, `ADValue`, `Key` and `Value`. On a match by match basis (each match will be an individual person) we will extract the person's name. Then there will be four individual lists of named match values held in `ADKey`, `ADValue`, `Key` and `Value`. Those represent the key value pairs of the data which we will `Zip` (you are using .net 4 right?) into dictionaries of key value pairs.

### C# Linq Logic

```
// Ignore pattern whitespace only allows us to comment the pattern
// it does not affect regex parsing.
// Explicit capture says only keep the items which fall within `(` and `)` for the final result.
// It is used to streamline the process somewhat for we don't need all the extraneous text/space.
Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => new
     {
        Name      = mt.Groups["Name"].Value,
        AdminInfo = mt.Groups["ADKey"].Captures
                                      .OfType<Capture>()
                                      .Select (cp => cp.Value)
                                      .Zip(mt.Groups["ADValue"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select (cp => cp.Value),
                                           (k,v) => new {key = k, value = v})
                                      .ToDictionary (cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value ),
        Nodes     = mt.Groups["Key"].Captures
                                      .OfType<Capture>()
                                      .Select (cp => cp.Value)
                                      .Zip(mt.Groups["Value"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select (cp => cp.Value),
                                           (k,v) => new {key = k, value = v})
                                      .ToDictionary (cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value ),

    })
```

This creates individual data entities where each match is *projected* into (that is what `Select` does it *projects* data from one form to another) an entity with properties of `Name`, `AdminInfo` and `Nodes`. `AdminInfo` and `Nodes` are dictionaries which hold 1 to many key value pairs. When processed against the data (below) this is the resulting data as shown in Linqpad

[image]

### Data

```
string text = @":client objects (
: (ThomasSmith
            :AdminInfo (
                :client_uid (""{C6DD9C9C-964A-4BE5-30F1-3D64A87F73A6}"")
                :nickName (Tom)
                )

            :addr (""1234 Pear Street"")
            :city (Charlotte)
            :state (NC)
            :zip (12345)
            :phone (""555-555-5555"")
            :email (""tom@someemailaddress.com"")
            :gender (male)

        )

: (Jonathan Thomson
            :AdminInfo (
                :client_uid (""{C6DD9C9C-964A-4BE5-30F1-3D64A87F73A7}"")
                :nickName (John)
                )

            :addr (""5678 Apple Street"")
            :city (""New York"")
            :state (NY)
            :zip (56789)
            :phone (""555-444-6666"")
            :email (""John@someemailaddress.com"")
        )
";
```

I leave it to you to process the ultimate entity result from above Regex.Matches call.

Comment: holy crap. this is possibly the most complete answer I've seen here. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the help, this got me a LONG way. However, I have run into An issue where the one of the properties also has an "Admin Info" and the regex broke down. I have tried about everything in my ability to handle this, and I'm not able to. I have update the data to show the additional child nodes. Apparently, this sub-node could potentially happen to any property.

Comment: @user2219930 it looks like any node can have an `AdminInfo`. In the State node you changed, where is the actual state text which should be there?

Comment: I have talked with the application developer, and it will either be the admin info, or the value... never both. I actually don't need to capture that information, apparently, if its admininfo for a sub-node, its completely useless. I only need it for the main object.

Comment: @user2219930 I am confused where is `NY` in state's main object?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. If the node, State for example, has "adminInfo", that means it was never filled out by the client and its effectively "null".  which, if possible, I would like to have a key of state and a value of null. but if thats not possible, I would like to just skip right over it.

If the property does not contain "adminInfo"  that means the client filled out the value, and that follows the pattern "state (NY)" for example.

one Caveat to this, is the "AdminInfo" section you originally helped me with. that holds some information that is critical to the client, such as ID

Comment: @user2219930 Ya this *unfortunately* is the "but it doesn't work for data yyyy" situation I feared. What you have is doable, but I don't have time to craft a solution. One can get a `key` (such as "State") but if there is a no value for the `value` the Linq select later will become out of sync. Long story short is that yes one can craft a process using regex, but due to my lack of time this week (end of a sprint and I am on vacation next week) I don't have time to take out of my schedule to craft one. I recommend that you take what was learned and continue plugging away. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you mean is not to completely stop reading, but to pause reading and then do some work on the lines in the preceding batch. For that, you could do something like:

```
public bool MatchesMyCondition(string line) {...}
public void DoSomething(List<string> lines) {...}

List<string> lines = new List<string>();
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("myFile.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (MatchesMyCondition(line))
    {
       DoSomething(lines);
       lines.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        lines.Add(line);
    }
}
//handle the last items
DoSomething(lines);
```

As Shenku said, using `someRegex.IsMatch(line)` is the most general-purpose way to look for something on a line, but `line.Contains(someSting)` could also be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommedn using [Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to process your file, anytime you are trying to grab string data based on a pattern it is clearly a winner.

Unfortunately it can be fairly complicated to get right, have a go on [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) to experiement and to get some reference info.

For example `\((.*?)\)` would grab all the values within your parenthisis.